# How to modify a numpy array using a function like excel

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm a little bit unfamiliar with numpy, and haven't been able to find the exact type of modification that I want to do to my array. I have an array like this:

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [4 5 6 7]
```

What I want to do is apply a function that will change every value in my array, but using the values of my array in the function itself (i.e. in excel you can write a function and modify your values using that function). To that end, I've been attempting to use numpy.apply_along_axis to do this, but I haven't been able to incorporate this into a loop to create the desired output. While the below code doesn't work, this is my logic flow so far (assume I've labeled the above matrix as M):

```
for values in M:
    def fun(a):
         return a[values]/(a[values]+a[0])
    q=np.apply_along_axis(fun,1,M)
```

The idea behind this is that it will take each element of each row, and divide it by the sum of that element + the very first element of that row. I.E.

```
[[1/(1+1) 2/(2+1) 3/(3+1) 4/(4+1)]
 [4/(4+4) 5/(5+4) 6/(6+4) 7(7+4)]]]
```

Comment: In general, numpy uses vectorization. You should think of it as a pipeline of operations, each of which is applied to the whole array at once. The posted answer shows how to do that: take the first column (a view into the original array), as it to the whole array (make a new array), divide the original by the new array elementwise (making a new array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a for loop. Just take advantage of [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]])

arr / (arr + arr[:,:1])
# array([[0.5       , 0.66666667, 0.75      , 0.8       ],
#        [0.5       , 0.55555556, 0.6       , 0.63636364]])
```

---

Here `arr[:,:1]` takes the first column of the array but keeps the shape as 2D, and then add it with `arr` itself which makes the denominator you needed:

```
arr[:, :1]
# array([[1],
#        [4]])

arr + arr[:, :1]
# array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```